3.5mm Dynamic Microphone Output into Mixer/Interface
I am hoping for a recommendation on the most simple product that can work as both a mixer (4 channels would be sufficient) and a mic preamp/converter for some variety of old/quirky microphones that have 3.5mm outputs.
I know that I need a large amount of input gain to get a usable signal from mics like this. To my understanding, that could be provided by either a separate mic preamp, or one built into a mixer/interface.
To put my question into its most specific form:

Can a microphone like the Sony MTL F-96 (dynamic mic, 600 ohm impedance) be used with this mixer, which boasts "mic preamps with ultra-wide 60dB gain range"?

If so, is a 3.5mm female to XLR male the adapter needed?


Thanks for any help; I'm very new to audio!
I've read through some similar questions, but they mostly referenced specific products with setups/use cases different than mine.

Going by the specs, I'd say that mixer can be used for the F-96. You'll want to use a 3.5mm female to XLR adapter: that mixer does have 6.3mm input jacks, but you lose 15 dB of gain when you use those. Might still be ok: most mics don't need more than 45 dB of gain, but you're going to need an adapter anyway to use the 6.3mm input so you might as well use an XLR adapter instead and get the extra gain in case it's needed.

To follow up: this answer was correct, but it didn’t truly work until I tried plugging in the F96 mic’s 1/8” output only halfway, rather than all the way into the XLR adapter. The takeaway is that the old mics are quirky, and 1/8” output jacks vary in their band/connection arrangement!
